# Android: GetMap() == null inside DialogFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-dialogfragment

Im trying put a MapFragment inside a DialogFragment, it works fine but i dont know how can I wait until getMap()!=null... here´s my code:

```
public class DialogMapa extends DialogFragment{

    private SupportMapFragment fragment;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog_mapa, container,false);
        getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.map, fragment).commit();    

        GoogleMap mapa = null;
        try {
             mapa =fragment.getMap();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (mapa==null) Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    return view;
    }

}
```

and my inflate layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the new maps framework, that call is not guaranteed to return non null. The map is pretty complex and is initializing a lot of state on and off the render thread.

In your case it's safe to call after `onFragmentsResumed()` or after the fragment is attached to an activity.  You could always use a handler to check again some point later.

Answer (score 0):

getMap() is not null inside onStart() of the dialog fragment, after view created.