# MapFragment.getMap( ) always returns null

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

`mMapFragment.getMap()` always returns null. I am supported from api level 12 onwards, so I am using `MapFragment` instead of `SupportMapFragment`.

```
public class MFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG = "map";
private GoogleMap mMap;
private MapFragment mMapFragment;
FragmentManager fm;
Context con;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    fm = getFragmentManager();
    con = getActivity();
      // It isn't possible to set a fragment's id programmatically so we set a tag instead and
    // search for it using that.
    mMapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);

    // We only create a fragment if it doesn't already exist.
    if (mMapFragment == null) {
        // To programmatically add the map, we first create a SupportMapFragment.
        mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();

        // Then we add it using a FragmentTransaction.
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
               fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add((R.id.mapframelayout, mMapFragment);  
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    // We can't be guaranteed that the map is available because Google Play services might
    // not be available.
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic, container, false);
    return v;
}



private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}
```

}

Can any one tell why it always returns null?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at this, it should help a bit, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689861/android-getmap-null-inside-dialogfragment/

Comment: I am calling setUpMapIfNeed() inside onResume()  but still it mMapFragment.getMap() returns null.

Comment: Ok? But I don't see that in this example? Are you using `SupportFragment`? Then I assume you should be using `onFragmentsResumed()` like it says in the other question I pointed you to. Don't use `onResumed()` and deal with fragments if you are using `FragmentActivity` or any Activity class that inherits from it

Comment: I am not using SupportFragment because i am supporting from api level 12 onwards.

Comment: OK well your code says otherwise, but like it says, if the Fragment isn't attached it will be null and if the view isn't fully craeted and map isn't fully created it will be null

Comment: I used onCreatedView() method to call SetUpMapIfNeeded() method but still it returns null.

Comment: onCreateView is telling the fragment to create the view. The view is not attached until this method returns. onViewCreated() might have more luck. It's still not guaranteed though. Like your comments say, it might not be available for various reasons (Google Play might not be on the device, taking time to initialize, error in your config, etc)

Comment: Sorry i used onViewCreated() method only but still it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no guarantee that the map fragment is ready when setUpMapIfNeeded  method is executed, this depends very much on the device, i´ve had devices that always have no problem and then others that exhibit similar behaviour as you describe.

The solution is to call setUpMapIfNeeded several times, the method is actually built for such use. I place one call in the OnCreate() and another in OnResume() and the problem has not reappeared on several hundred devices. Try the same, i.e. add the method call on onResume in your Fragment.

If the problem persists, I recommend switching over to the SupportMapFragment and see if that helps.